# Invalid MIDI message Data when I'm trying to send Control Change Messages

Tags: python, python-2.7, midi, pyportmidi

I'm using pygame.midi library to send MIDI Messages (Control Change messages, not notes).
The idea is to send from the output (from this python program) to the input of another program.

```
>>> import time
>>> import pygame.midi as midi
>>> midiout = midi.Output(3)
>>> midi.init()
>>> midiout = midi.Output(3)
>>> midiout.write_short(0x74,124,0)
PortMidi call failed...
  PortMidi: `Invalid MIDI message Data'
type ENTER...
```

As you can see, i'm sending 0x74,124,0. I'm taking those numbers from rakarrack (the application that i want to control) implementation chart: http://rakarrack.sourceforge.net/midiic.html

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIDI status bytes (the first byte of the message) must have the high (0x80) bit set. the linked chart is a bit confusing, but I'm guessing 0x74 is a data byte and must be preceded by the proper status byte.

```
>>> import pygame.midi as midi
>>> midi.init()
>>> midiout = midi.Output(0)
>>> midiout.write_short(0xb0, 0x74, 124)
```

some basic MIDI documentation: http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php

control change is 0xbn, where n is the channel number, so 0xb0 is a control change message for channel 0.

Comment: Where the '0x80' comes from? I don't see in the chart.

Comment: I just updated with a link to status codes. 0x80 is "note off" on channel 0, probably not what you want; I just used it as an example.

Comment: Comparing both MIDI charts I figured out that the 0x74 should be the second byte, and 124 is the value of on/off (which replaces velocity). The question is, what is the first byte value?

Comment: since I have no knowledge of rakarrack, my guess would be a "note on" event, 0x9n, where n is the channel. 0x90 for channel 0 for example.

Comment: mmmm... python accepted like a valid instruction, however rakarrack doesn't do anything. I don't think it should be a note on event, because this is not a playing device (like a syntetizer or sampler).

Comment: I already change the output device, but it doesn't do anything when i send that instruction. Maybe I'm still using the wrong first byte.

Comment: you'll need to find and study some documentation on rakarrack.

Comment: control change is 0xb0 [sorry, it took me a while to put two and two together -- it's been years since I studied MIDI]

Comment: I read more carefully the MIDI Implementation of the chart that you provided. The first byte that I should send is "0xb0" which corresponds to "Chan 1 Control/Mode Change". And it works!

Comment: Thanks! i figured out myself anyway :P